# Send a message multiple times all at once in Python

Tags: python, sockets

In python 3.5 is it possible to send multiple messages with `sock.send(msg) * 10`. In this case will it send 10 times or just one time and have some sort of error in the background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if list-creation side-effect is not a problem, then you can do it as a list comprehension as well:

```
[sock.send(msg) for _ in range(10)]
```

`_` is a sort of "throwaway" variable, you can use any other identifier name there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call `sock.send(msg)` ten times, you can use a `for` loop as such:

```
for x in range(0,9):
    sock.send(msg)
```

*Reference: https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop*